# CSV on Bash: How can I get the last state of specific field in a ordered list (log file)?

Tags: bash, csv

I have a simple script that checks if backups are up to date on different computers when these computers are on (this is: at **irregular frequencies**) and writes the state to a log **CSV file** (say *logfile.csv*).

Say computers are *Restaurant*, *Office*, *Reception* and *Hall*. I get the **log** (ordered by date, first field) :

```
$ cat logfile.csv
2019-02-15,Restaurant,Outdated
2019-02-16,Office,Updated
2019-02-21,Restaurant,Updated
2019-02-21,Reception,Updated
2019-02-21,Hall,Updated
2019-02-22,Hall,Outdated
2019-02-22,Reception,Updated
2019-02-23,Office,Updated
```

How could I get on **Bash** the last (actual) **state of each computer** (field 2) ?

On my **example**, the desired results should yield:

```
2019-02-21,Restaurant,Updated
2019-02-22,Hall,Outdated
2019-02-22,Reception,Updated
2019-02-23,Office,Updated
```

Answer (score 3):

There may be a prettier way to do this, but with awk:

```
awk -F"," '{a[$2]=$0}END{for(line in a){print a[line]}}' logfile.csv | sort
```

All that's doing is adding each line (`$0`) to an array (`a`) where the key of the array is the place (`$2`)(restaurant, hall, etc). The element in the array is overwritten with whatever was last encountered as it reads through the rows. At the `END` we iterate and print out the array. This is passed to sort to get the chronological order back.

Comment: Correct answer. The `sort` part is not actually a need, but makes output more readable. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

You could reverse the file and print the line the **first** time you see something new:

```
tac logfile.csv | awk -F, '!seen[$2]++'
```

This is a famous awk idiom: `seen[$2]++` returns zero the first time, then `!seen[$2]++` inverts that into a "true" value. All other values are inverted into "false".

If you know beforehand how many computers you expect to see, you could exit early:

```
tac logfile.csv | awk -F, -v num=4 '!seen[$2]++ {print; if (++count == num) exit}'
```

Comment: A very useful optimization, indeed (a log file could become very big as time goes by).